# Java code instrumentation to record every access to classes fields

Tags: java, aspectj, instrumentation

I would like to ask if please someone can suggest me which is the most
suitable instrumentation library for accomplishing the following task:

Given a huge Java program source code I need to instrument it in order
to run the program and log the following information:

For each class and for each access to its fields

- if is a read or a write access
- the value that has been read or wrote
- the line code number of the class where the access is located
- the name of the method where the access has been performed

Comment: My advice is don't do it. You're going to gather so much data that you won't be able to truly digest it all. Instead, I would focus more on the issues being identified by users and product owners and concentrate your efforts there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way to do this kind of trace is using AOP. There are several mature libraries for AOP in java. To start something with, take a look [at this example](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/30799/1954).

I'm not sure about logging direct access to fields, but you could read them with getters (private or protected if you don't want to expose these fields to public).